# Expanding and contracting DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am currently working on a project that displays user data in a grid, each user has a total and when clicked expands out to show the sub items that make up that total and they can be expanded again to show even more details.

I currently achieve this by using a DataGridView with its data bound to a DataTable, I hide the sub items for each user in the "RowsAdded" event and then just show/hide them as the main user lines/sub lines are clicked.
The Main problem with this is the scroll bar jumps a lot when data is changed and I require it to only move when the user wants it to.
I also have a requirement that no line must ever be covered and the parent lines should show totals of the values in the child (I can do this part manually the more important part is that its not a grouping like with a outlook style list).

My question is: Is there a better way to have expanding entries in a table format? And if hiding and un-hiding is the only way then any idea how to fix the scrolling problem?

I have tried hiding and showing lines as I have already said and I have also tried hiding and showing another Control (in this case another DataGridView) the problem with this approach is that it covers the other rows as I have yet to find a suable way to pad out a space for the control to be in.

Comment: Are you talking about something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/451742/Extending-Csharp-ListView-with-Collapsible-Groups)

Comment: Added more details, my apologies I wasn't more clear before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the End there was no satisfactory way to do this with winforms so I was forced to swap to WPF and I had everything running in about 2 hours.

My end solution was to use a DataGrid with rowdetails that contain a DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to eliminate the scrolling animation.

```
dataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;

// Do your show/hide on your datagridview rows

dataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
```

Comment: Using this the scroll bar doesn't function at all it always goes back to the top every update and if you do get it to move it will then reset to that point over and over.